# Magit commit error: "cannot spawn sh" + "cannot start editor"

Tags: magit, emacsclient

When I try to commit using Magit, I get the following error message:

> 1 c:/Users/chanyoungs/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db/cmd/git.exe … "commit" "--"
>
> error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
>
> error: unable to start editor '"c:/Users/chanyoungs/Documents/Programming/emacs/emacs-25.1/bin/emacsclient.exe"'
>   Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.

Here are my settings:

- Windows 10 64bit
- GNU Emacs 25.2.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32)
  of 2017-04-24
- Magit ver. 20170425.638
- Git ver. 2.11.0.windows.3
- Running Daemon

Further checks:

- When I call git on cmd, it is called successfully
- When I call emacsclient on cmd, in is called successfully
- I tried running emacs with no other packages and get the same error

I searched for this error around and there are similar questions but I can't fix this with their suggestions. May be I'm not doing this right.

Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: What's the output from `git -c "alias.X=!x() { which \"$1\" | cygpath -mf -; }; x" X sh` in cmd? Does `c:/Users/chanyoungs/AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\usr\bin` exist?

Comment: Thanks @npostavs for the quick comment.

1. When I run `git -c "alias.X=!x() { which \"$1\" | cygpath -mf -; }; x" X sh` on cmd I get:

`error: cannot spawn sh: No such file or directory
fatal: While expanding alias 'X': 'x() { which "$1" | cygpath -mf -; }; x': No such file or directory`

2. Yes, I just tried to find `c:/Users/chanyoungs/AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a‌​78695063deace08e96d5‌​042710d3e32db\usr\bi‌​n` in cmd just now and I can confirm that it exists.

Comment: Hmm, does that `.../usr/bin/` directory not contain a `sh.exe` file? Can you run `c:/Users/chanyoungs/AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a‌​‌​78695063deace08e96‌​d5‌​042710d3e32db/git-bash.exe` and try `which sh` in that shell? (and also `cygpath -m $(which sh)` if that doesn't error out)

Comment: 1. `usr/bin/` folder does contain `sh.exe`
2. `c:/Users/chanyoungs/AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a‌​‌​‌​78695063deace08e‌​96‌​d5‌​042710d3e32d‌​b/git-bash.exe` runs `MINGW32`
3. `chanyoungs@DESKTOP-L4TTJ2L MINGW32 /c/Users/chanyoungs
$ which sh` gives `/usr/bin/sh`
4. `chanyoungs@DESKTOP-L4TTJ2L MINGW32 /c/Users/chanyoungs
$ cygpath -m $(which sh)` gives `C:/Users/chanyoungs/AppData/Local/GitHub/PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5                                                                                                                 042710d3e32db/usr/bin/sh.exe`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying various things, I realised that "sh" is not recognised in cmd so I tried to add the path to "sh.exe" in the environment variable. This seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my .emacs.d/init i removed my custom line:

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Users/username/PortableGit/mingw64/bin")
```

, so the only customized lines left were:

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Users/username/PortableGit/usr/bin")
(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/Users/username/PortableGit/bin")
```

There are multiple executables in the git-folder. Adding the wrong ones to `exec-path` does more harm than good.